# How can I import a function into my QTP test while it's running?

Tags: function, vbscript, import, qtp

I've built many functions for my QTP 10 tests, and many of those functions rely on other, related functions. I would like to have my functions import any other functions that they require. Currently, I have to go through each of my functions and associate each of their dependencies by hand.

While I'm aware that `ExecuteFile "C:\Functions\SampleFunction.vbs"` would work, the downside is that QTP is unable to display any of the code it just imported. That means that debugging the code is a nightmare, since QTP will show that yellow debugging pointer on lines that don't correspond to the code actually being run. Long story short, that approach is a mess.

Is there any other command that will import other .vbs files into QTP during runtime, so I can have the functions import the other functions they require?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a post by Anish Pillai called "4 Different Ways to Associate Function Libraries to your QTP Scripts", that has some useful info. (See the original post here: http://www.automationrepository.com/2011/09/associate-function-library-to-qtp-script/ )

**Method #1** is the usual way to associate functions with a test; nothing new there.

**Method #2** Using AOM (Automation Object Model)
I've tried many different variations, but all of them seem to be scripts for launching a specific test from outside of QTP, not for adding a function to a running test.
Here's their code in case it proves useful:

```
'Open QTP
Set objQTP = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application")
objQTP.Launch
objQTP.Visible = True

'Open a test and associate a function library to the test
objQTP.Open "C:\Automation\SampleTest", False, False
Set objLib = objQTP.Test.Settings.Resources.Libraries

'If the library is not already associated with the test case, associate it..
If objLib.Find("C:\SampleFunctionLibrary.vbs") = -1 Then ' If library is not already added
  objLib.Add "C:\SampleFunctionLibrary.vbs", 1 ' Associate the library to the test case
End
```

**Method #3** Using ExecuteFile Method
Has the same downfalls that I brought up in the question. Could be useful, but it's horrible for debugging within QTP 10.

**Method #4** Using LoadFunctionLibrary Method
This is the most promising approach. It appears to do exactly what we need it to: load vbscript function libraries while the test is running. The only catch? **It appears to be QTP 11+ only**. I can't vouch for this method since I don't have QTP 11, but it looks like the perfect approach.

```
LoadFunctionLibrary "C:\YourFunctionLibrary_1.vbs" 'Associate a single function library
LoadFunctionLibrary "C:\FuncLib_1.vbs", "C:\FuncLib_2.vbs" 'Associate more than 1 function libraries
```

Comment: Do you know if there are negative side effects with `LoadFunctionLibrary` and reloading the same library multiple times (like you would do with `@import` or `using` in other libraries)? QTP10 user here, but just curious because... you know, I just want to know.

Comment: The only negative I am aware of relating to `LoadFunctionLibrary` vs `ExecuteFile` is that `LoadFunctionLibrary` doesn't support user defined classes.

Comment: Even with Method 3, if you are working with the excels they will be renamed and you won'τ be able to find them!

Comment: The other negative that I just found out is that `GetRef` will not work if you are fetching any function from any imported FL via `LoadFunctionLibrary`. However, if you use `ExecuteFile`, it works