# How to call a function (with parameters) which is in function library, taking the function name from a variable?

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I'm trying to use getref to call a function from the function library associated with the test.
My code -

In action1

```
str = "sample"
msg = "hi"
x = GetRef("Function_"&str)(msg)
msgbox x
```

In the function Library,

```
Function Function_sample(strMsg)
    Function_sample = strMsg
End Function
```

I'm getting the error -

> "Invalid procedure call or argument."

But it works fine if the function is placed in the same action.
How to call a function (with parameters) which is in function library, taking the function name from a variable?

Comment: as your code 'works' as a plain VBScript, there must be a problem with your (including of the) library.

Comment: I don't think [`GetRef`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekabbe10) works in plain VBScript.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - of course it does, see my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

Minimalistic working example:

**Lib.vbs:**

```
Option Explicit

Function Twice(n)
  Twice = n + n
End Function
```

**Main.vbs:**

```
Option Explicit

Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

ExecuteGlobal goFS.OpenTextFile(".\lib.vbs").ReadAll()

Dim fpTwice : Set fpTwice = GetRef("Twice")

WScript.Echo fpTwice(42)
```

**Output:**

```
cscript main.vbs
84
```

The error message "... runtime error: Invalid procedure call or argument: 'GetRef'" indicates that the (importing of the) function library is to blame.

**Update:**

I **think** that it is plausible to assume that the VBScript engine keeps a table associating sub/function/method names with callable code to be able to do literal/direct calls:

```
n = Twice(11)
```

and that GetRef("Twice") accesses this table. So I would never expect an indirect/'function pointer' call or a GetRef() to fail when the literal invocation succeeds.

But according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300197/how-can-i-import-a-function-into-my-qtp-test-while-its-running) and [that](http://www.automationrepository.com/2011/09/associate-function-library-to-qtp-script/), there are at least four ways to 'import' libraries/modules into QTP, and *as I don't use QTP* I can't rule out, that some (or even all) of these methods do something silly to cause the mis-behaviour you describe.

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with my (importing of the) function library as it works fine if I call the function directly (by the function name) without using getref.

Comment: @Saranya - verify that the error occurs on the GetRef() line; isolate the GetRef() call; publish more of your code (how do you 'import' a library in QTP?); could it be a problem of sequence/order (like calling before the library is loaded)?

Comment: I have associated the function library with my test and I'm able to call other functions from the action. Also, when I tried calling the function using getref within the function library, it worked fine. But I get the error when I call the function using getref from the action.  Does getref work only for local functions?

Comment: In my experience (for which I do not have an explaination), it should work, but fails if the GetRef call is in a library function, AND that function  is registered as a test object method via RegisterUserFunc, AND the function called via the test object method. Is that your scenario?

Comment: @Saranya - GetRef() works for Global/Public functions/subs *and* even for Local/Private ones.

Comment: @TheBlastOne - I have not registered the function using RegisterUserFunc. I have associated the function library with my test by using ‘File > Settings > Resources > Associate Function Library’ option in QTP.

Comment: @Saranya - Instead of associating FLs via menu, use `ExecuteFile` and then `GetRef` will work.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41851543/getref-not-working-if-function-is-loaded-at-runtime-using-loadfunctionlibrary) and found out that associating or loading the functional libraries doesn't work for `GetRef`. To work around this issue, all you need to do is instead of associating or loading your FL, execute it using `ExecuteFile` function.

In action1

```
ExecuteFile "/path/functionallibrary.vbs"
str = "sample"
msg = "hi"
x = GetRef("Function_" & str)(msg)
msgbox x
```